# How to update Parent component from Child component in React (Functional)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I have the following functional component called RoomManagement. On the first render, fetchRooms gets called, which in turn initially set the state variables with data from a database.

I have a child component called RoomManagementModal, where I pass both my setLoading and fetchRooms function.

I'm having trouble re-rendering the parent component. I click a button in the child component (this adds something to the database). So I'm trying to then get the new data by calling `props.fetch()` once again but this time from the child, which I thought would trigger a state change on the parent, but it doesn't seem that way.

I can't seem to find a way to kind of force the parent component to render again, if that is possible

```
function RoomManagement() {

    const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);
    const [unavailableRooms, setUnavailableRooms] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const fetchRooms = async () => {
        await getAllRooms().then((res) => {
            res.json().then(data => setRooms(data))
        });
        await getAllRoomsUnavailable().then((res) => {
            res.json().then(data => setUnavailableRooms(data[0]))
        })
        setLoading(false)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchRooms();
    }, []);
    
    return (.....
   <RoomManagementModal setLoading={setLoading} fetch={fetchRooms}/>
)

}
export default RoomManagement;
```

```
<Button
          onClick={() => {
            if (form.room_id && form.start && form.end) {
              createRoomUnavailable(form).then((res) => {
                if (res.status != 200 && res.status != 201) {
                  res.text().then((e) => setError(e));
                } else {
                  props.fetch()
                }
              });
            } else {
              setError("Missing required Room Id or date time.");
            }
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
```

Comment: Pass a function down to the child which updates the parent state.

Comment: @evolutionxbox isn't that what they attempted to do? fetchRooms is a function which updates the parent state, and they're passing it down to the child.

Comment: @NicholasTower the OP hasn't shown how it is used within the child component.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm not sure why you would say that. They *did* show the code where the child calls `props.fetch()`. Do you just mean you need more information about the surrounding code?

Answer (score 1):

Parent component

1.Declare a state and a setter for the title or slug
2.Define a function to update the state
3.Pass that function down as props to the child component

Child Component

1.Define a function that handles and calls the function passed as props
2.from the parent component